# Transverse through LI to collect checked boxes group by UL using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a primary product array

```
var prodArr = new Array('Microsoft', 'Google');
```

Using prodArr as the primary loop, I created a UL LI checkboxtree which looks as follows:

```
<ul id="prodTree">
  <li>
    <input name="prod" id="prod" type="checkbox" value="Microsoft">
    <label>Microsoft</label>
    <ul id="MicrosoftTree">
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod" type="checkbox" value="msp1">
          <label>Microsoft Product 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod" type="checkbox" value="msp2">
          <label>Microsoft Product 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
    <input name="prod" id="prod" type="checkbox" value="Google">
    <label>Google</label>
    <ul id="GoogleTree">
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod" type="checkbox" value="gp1">
          <label>Google Product 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod" type="checkbox" value="gp2">
          <label>Google Product 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

On click of a button, I want to use prodArr and loop through every UL and group all the checkbox checked and create a textbox out of it. Lets assume 'msp1', 'msp2' and 'msp9' Microsoft products were selected. Example:

```
<input type='text' id='Microsoft' value='msp1, msp2, msp9' />
```

I have tried. Please help.

Comment: What's the purpose of this input you are generating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-selector to select only checked checkboxes, and you can iterate over the matched set and get the values using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#prodTree :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/LqFWG/1/) of the above.

Comment: Database does not contain 'Primary product' column. It just contains individual product list.

Is they a way you can iterate through prodArr and get checked boxes grouped by primary product and add them to input box please

Comment: Code snippet is amazing, but this will list all selected. No way to distinguish primary versus products contained within each category.

parent
  --- child
  --- child

If we are able to distinguish between them, then I can create a text box grouping countries.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? You'd do better to handle it server side. If you change the `name`s of your `input`s like so:

```
<ul id="prodTree">
  <li>
    <ul id="MicrosoftTree">
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod[microsoft][]" type="checkbox" value="msp1">
          <label>Microsoft Product 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod[microsoft][]" type="checkbox" value="msp2">
          <label>Microsoft Product 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="GoogleTree">
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod[google][]" type="checkbox" value="gp1">
          <label>Google Product 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input id="prod" name="prod[google][]" type="checkbox" value="gp2">
          <label>Google Product 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Then in your PHP code, you can do this:

```
$checkboxes = $_GET['prod'];
print_r($checkboxes['microsoft']); // Array('msp1', 'msp2'), if both are checked
print_r($checkboxes['google']); // Array('gp1', 'gp2'), if both are checked
```

Comment: Where did you found that this question is related to PHP?

Comment: @Samich: Why else would you generate `<input type='text' id='Microsoft' value='msp1, msp2, msp9' />`? The only reason you'd use an `input` is if you were going to submit it to the server, since that's clearly not supposed to be edited. My answer says that you shouldn't need to generate it, as form submitting is cleverer than you might think.

Comment: Yes, but it can be any other language and it can be sent via AJAX request at all.

Comment: @Samich: Yes, it can be any server-side language, but I made a guess that it was PHP, since that is most common. I'm not sure what you mean by "it can be sent via AJAX request at all".

Comment: Database does not contain 'Primary product' column. It just contains individual product list.

Is they a way you can iterate through prodArr and get checked boxes grouped by primary product and add them to input box please

Comment: @Genx: What do you mean? Neither you nor I mentioned a database!

Comment: No, its not PHP
We have looked at different way and this is the best way out of the current problem (without modifying existing infrastructure)

iterating through primary prodArr, collecting the checked check boxes and grouping them into text boxes.

Comment: The client is using Django framework with Python. He created these forms using jQuery and javascript.

The style of using 'name="prod[google][]"' wont work because this either requires Django forms or some sort of models, which client is not interested in.

Therefore iterating using primary prodArr, collecting checked check boxes and grouping them into text boxes is the way out for us

Comment: Is `prod[google][]` a PHP-only feature? I thought it was part of some larger spec. At any rate, it would probably make much more sense to handle, and generate, the forms server-side.

Comment: I agree that its a part of larger spec. But the handling varies with frameworks in middle

Answer (score 0):

I tried it a bit. This may not be 'the' answer, but I got what I wanted

```
$("#regions:checked").each(function(){ 
  var x= "";
  var regionName = $(this).val();
  var treeName = "#"+$(this).val()+"Tree :checkbox:checked";
  var countryVal="";
  $(treeName).each(function(){ 
    if(countryVal != '') { countryVal += ','; }
      countryVal += $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Feel free to suggest a better answer or technique to get this result.